# How to link two delegates in different classes?

Tags: c#, events, delegates, action

I have two different classes, say `Outer` and `Inner`. An instance of `Inner` is a field in the `Outer`. My goal is to link the `ActionInner` and `ActionOuter`; in other words, when I add an action for `ActionOuter`, I want it to be added to `ActionInner`. How can I do it?

Here is my attempt that does not work, because both actions are nulls:

```cs
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Outer outer = new Outer();

            void writeToConsole(double foo)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(foo);
            }

            // Here I expect to link the 'writeToConsole' action to 'inner' 'ActionInner'
            outer.ActionOuter += writeToConsole;

            // Here I expect an instance of 'inner' to output '12.34' in console
            outer.StartAction();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class Inner
    {
        public Action<double> ActionInner;

        public void DoSomeStuff(double foo)
        {
            ActionInner?.Invoke(foo);
        }
    }

    class Outer
    {
        readonly Inner inner;

        public Action<double> ActionOuter;

        public void StartAction()
        {
            inner.DoSomeStuff(12.34);
        }

        public Outer()
        {
            inner = new Inner();

            // Here I want to somehow make a link between two actions
            inner.ActionInner += ActionOuter;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This post needs  more clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `ActionOuter` fields to property. Set and get like below;

```
public Action<double> ActionOuter
    {
        set => inner.ActionInner = value;
        get => inner.ActionInner;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Consider using [Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties) for your class. Using properties allows you to have certain things happen when a property is retrieved or set with a new value.

For example if we implement a property for `ActionOuter` we can, every time `ActionOuter` is set, check to see if we have an `inner` and maybe set it's value.

When you use a [setter(set accessor)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties#the-set-accessor) (like below) you can use the special keyword `value` that denotes the value that was passed along when `ActionOuter` was assigned to last. This is the value you would use to set the private `actionOuter` and possibly the `inner.ActionInner` if you want.

```cs
private Action<double> actionOuter;
public Action<double> ActionOuter{
    get => actionOuter;
    set{
        // do something here, maybe set inner's value?
        actionOuter = value;
    }
}
```